# Getting Error when deploying on Tomcat

Tags: gwt, tomcat, web-deployment-project

I have already compiled my application, when I am running it in web
mode from Eclipse everything is working perfectly fine, no error at
all. In my project, i'm using several libraries such as hibernate. All
libraries have been correctly been placed on the classpath as well as
in the lib folder in web-inf.

however when i'm deploying it on tomcat, i'm getting several problem,
first no data is being loaded from database. I was using a lib for
capcha at http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/06/add-captcha-gwt-application.html. That also is not working well

I am also trying it on Jetty with the same problem

Can someone please help, i've got to deploy this system??

Comment: It's hard to tell with no code to see. Be sure to debug you application properly (set up your eclipe to debug on remote server).

Comment: Can u guide me about how to do this bcause i always debug in production mode

Comment: I already answered how to debug on external tomcat here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848198/debug-gwt-application-with-tomcat-eclipse/4857661#4857661

Comment: The only thing I'm not understanding is that in production mode, everything is working perfectly but when i'm taking the same war file and placing it on tomcat, it is not working!!

Comment: Be sure to include all required libraries in your /war/WEB-INF/lib folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to include all required libraries in your /war/WEB-INF/lib folder

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it was a problem of lib, whenever deploying your app on the server, make sure that u have the required libs that r on your classpath in the folder webinf/lib.

Comment: I posted original comment as answer then.

Comment: @ Xorty, I was intending to put some more resources in the answer, but i didn't get the time for e.g. configuring log4j or hibernate propeties file. However, credit goes to you because it was your answer that guided me to recompile my app with all the req libs, thanks