# Remote debug in Tomcat 6

Tags: eclipse, gwt, tomcat6

Does anyone know the steps to configure remote debugging in Tomcat 6 for GWT applications?

IDE - Eclipse

Sever - Tomcat6

Tech - GWT

I have gone through the following link, but it was not clear for me.

http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Developing

**I have done the following things:**

1. Placed the project war in 'Catalina_Home/webapps/project' which I wanted to debug remotely.
2. Opened tomcat6w.exe and pasted java option under java tab as follows:

   `-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n`
3. Clicked on start. After starting the server, I have opened eclipse the configure the remote debugging with port 8000 and click on Debug.
4. I have got the error message back saying that  `Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused`.

Is there anything else that I am missing here. Please correct me if I am wrong any where.

Comment: What exactly isn't clear for You? More details, facts please.

Comment: @tostao - i have updated my question.Added more information about the steps i have followed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848198/debug-gwt-application-with-tomcat-eclipse Is this the answer on your question?

Answer (score 9):

Use command line, go to your Tomcat folder `..\Tomcat6\bin` and write command:

```
catalina jpda start
```

Wait until Tomcat will run (You will see something like) :

[image: tomcat started]

Then in eclipse: `Debug -> Debug configuration -> Remote Java Application -> New`

[image: debug configuration] Browse a project and debug!

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. When i try to execute the 'catalina jpda start' in command prompt under '...Tomcat6/bin' directory, this is what the response:    'C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\bin>catalina jpda start
'catalina' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.'

Comment: Please download Tomcat6 one more time ( http://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi ). Try on this "fresh" version.

Comment: One more thing is that i don't find any start up bat file under ....Tomcat6/bin/... directory. Instead of that i have the 'tomcat6.exe' file

Comment: I don't know what version of tomcat do You have. Please download new one and just try what I wrote.

Comment: I have downloaded the tomcat(tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi) and followed the debug steps mentioned above. But when i run the application it is not hitting any debug point.

Answer (score 6):

Use the following :

`"-Xdebug"` and `"-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"` in two different lines, without qoutes in tomcat6w.exe > Java tab > Java Options (before everything else) and apply.

Then you just need to configure a Remote Java Application profile in Debug Configuration of Eclipse for your project and point it to the same jpda port.